# Random name generator/warper with parameters?

Tags: php, excel, random, generator, rename

I'd like to use Excel and VBA-script if possible or PHP. I'd really appreciate any answers, even offsite to my idea.

I'd like to know if anyone could hint me on how to twist regular names into somewhat random fantasy-ish names?

I'D like to have two columns with first name and surname, and then run a script looking for similarities to a set number of parameters on sheet 2.

Something like the generators "What's your XXX name?" but on a more serious note and not totally random.

I would prefer to have the possibility to match some characters in a persons name(s).

If my real name was David Cameron - the "converter" should come up with a possible result (from set parameters) like "Widor Merserine". Why?

I´d set the script to look at 3 characters in the first name, randomly (if possible) choosing v, I and d and matching them to the fantasy name Widor (were the three letters can be found). 
The same happens with the surname column, the three letters "mer" gets picked and converts the name to "Merserine".

Comment: Nothing random about "What's your XXX name?" it was a password reset secret question phishing scam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this of any value to you, but Excel is a great tool for creating *anagrams*

Place a word (20 letters or less) in cell **A1**
In cells **B1** thru **B20** enter

```
=RAND()
```

In cell **C1** enter:

```
=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$20,1)+COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)-1
```

and copy down thru **C20**
In **D1** enter:

```
=MID($A$1,C1,1)
```

and copy down thru **D20.**  Finally in **E1** enter:

```
=D1 & D2 & D3 & D4 & D5 & D6 & D7 & D8 & D9 & D10 & D11 & D12 & D13 & D14 & D15 & D16 & D17 & D18 & D19 & D20
```

**E1** will contain the anagram.  For example:

[image: anagram]

Each re-calculation will generate a new anagram.  With a tiny bit of **VBA** you could list all 5000+ anagrams of *climate.*